# Get error message to use github Liquid Swipe package

Tags: android, github

I am going to use liquid swipe package for my android app. ( https://github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android ).
So I did every thing step by step according to the it's manual.
I have generated my account key and token from my github account and added gpr.user and gpr.key then added dependencies. but when I built my app I will get this error message.

```
"Username must not be null!"

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0.
Required by:
project :app
> Could not resolve com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android/com/cuberto/liquid-swipe/1.0.0/liquid-swipe-1.0.0.pom'.
> Username must not be null!

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

my github.properties:

```
gpr.user = user
gpr.key = key
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

`https://api.github.com/users/<github username>`

Run the above on your browser. This will return a json. In that json, you will see an id, that's your `gpr user`

For the token, go to developer setting in your github and create a token.

Note: Make sure to tick read packages